# How to model a BigQuery external table for changing the column structure?

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl

I have a 5 columns, c1, c2, c3,c4, c5 in source table (MySQL). I exported the table and added in GCS like gs://data/table_name/YYYYMMDD/table_nameYYYYMMDDHHMMSS.csv

And I exported the data for the 3 months of data.

In later stages, two new columns say c6 and c7 added. Now the exported files in gs://data/table_name will have 7 columns

And there is a chance that c4 column is being removed as well. So the exported files will have 6 columns, i.e. c1, c2, c3, c5, c6, c7

How the external table can be modelled to adapt to these changes?

Comment: *"How the external table can be modelled to adapt to these changes?"* *"I have a 5 columns, c1, c2, c3,c4, c5 in source table (MySQL)."*  if column names have incrementing numbers they are most likely (very) good candidates for normalisation.  Which you most likely should look into then you can simply INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE records between the servers.

Comment: Is it the same csv filename less the c4 column + c6 and c7? or is this a new csv file with c1, c2, c3, c5, c6, c7 with the same data as the first csv file less the c4 column + c6 and c7? Please elaborate your use-case

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change table schema?

Try `bq update` command.

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas .

Like this.

```
$ bq show --schema --format=prettyjson projectId:Dataset.Table > schema.json

$ vim schema.json
---> Modify schema setting

$ bq update projectId:Dataset.Table schema.json
```